# React-native combine redux-persist with local and sensitive storage

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, storage, redux-persist

Here's the situation:
I develop an application in React Native in which I store connection data (id, token, and a boolean for automatic login).
Until then, I used to store everything locally with AsyncStorage without worries.

I then tried to set up redux-persist-sensitive-storage to securely store the token so that a user can't easily access it by snooping through the local data.

I searched in the various documentations, like these for example :
- https://github.com/CodingZeal/redux-persist-sensitive-storage
- https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#nested-persistsf
- https://blog.reactnativecoach.com/the-definitive-guide-to-redux-persist-84738167975

But I can't find cases where different types of storage are used together, and I can't produce a functional result.

Here are my different parts of code:
- The configuration of my store.

```
//Store/configureStore.js

import {combineReducers, createStore} from 'redux'
import authenticateReducer from './Reducers/authenticateReducer'
import tokenReducer from './Reducers/tokenReducer';
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import createSensitiveStorage from "redux-persist-sensitive-storage"
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';



// Si besoin d'un type de stockage classique, voir doc redux-persist-sensitive-storage pour combinaison de plusieurs types de stockages
//Attendre ejction pour utilisation données sécurisées

const sensitiveStorage = createSensitiveStorage({
    keychainService: "myKeychain",
    sharedPreferencesName: "mySharedPrefs"
});

// const mainPersistConfig = {
//     key: 'main',
//     storage: storage
// }

const tokenPersistConfig = {
    key: "tokene",
    storage: sensitiveStorage
}

const authPersistConfig = {
    key: 'auth',
    storage: AsyncStorage
}

const mainReducer = combineReducers({
    main: persistReducer(authPersistConfig, authenticateReducer),
    token: persistReducer(tokenPersistConfig, tokenReducer)
})

export default createStore(mainReducer)
```

- App.js

```
//App.js

import React from 'react';
import Navigation from './Navigation/Navigation'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import Store from './Store/configureStore'
import {persistStore} from 'redux-persist'
import {PersistGate} from 'redux-persist/es/integration/react'

class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        let persistor = persistStore(Store)
        console.log("store" + JSON.stringify(Store))
        return (
            //Le provider permet de distribuer le Store Redux dans toute l'application
            <Provider store={Store}>
                <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
                    <Navigation/>
                </PersistGate>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

- And here's the part that connects to the awning on my starting view.
  Here I ended up getting confused in my attempts and I don't really know how to get back the value of my token.

`token: state.tokenReducer.token,`
ou
`token: state.mainReducer.token,`
ect..

```
//Connexion du state global de l'application
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log("state:" +JSON.stringify(state))
    return {
        token: state.tokenReducer.token,
        id: state.authenticateReducer.id,
        autolog: state.authenticateReducer.autolog
    }
}
```

A little help to enable me to use both methods of storage would be welcome!

Thank you very much.